# Accepting multiple payloads from a Retrofit API request

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

My Retrofit API method is currently accepting one payload structure. However, the backend may return a different payload structure if there's any error in the request.

For example:

```
public void search(String term, final CallBack <ArrayList<String>> callBack) {
    RetroGenerator.createService(APIServices.class).search(term).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    callBack.onSuccess(response.body());
                }

                return;
            }
            callBack.onError();
        }

        @Override public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {
            callBack.onError();
        }
    });
}
```

The backend is returning an array of String values. However if an error occurs, backend may return the following payload structure:

```
{
   "error": "Term can't be empty",
   "code": 403
}
```

But the way my API method is setup, it only accepts one java model.

**API Interface:**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v1/search.json")
Call<ArrayList<String>> search(@Field("term") String term);
```

Currently it's accepting only an `ArrayList<String>` and does not accept the custom error payload model. Given that I create a new model called `Error`:

```
public class Error {
   public String error;
   public int code;
}
```

How can I switch the retrofit API method's model when an error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an ErrorUtils class to handle your unsuccessful responses:

public class ErrorUtils {

```
public static ApiError parseError(Response<?> response) {
    Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter = ServiceGenerator.retrofit().
            responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, new Annotation[0]);

    ApiError apiError;

    try {
        apiError = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        apiError = new ApiError();
    }

    return apiError;
}
```

}

Then when you find an unsuccessful response, just parse the response with the ErrorUtils class:

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    // ...
    ApiError apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
}
```

The ApiError class:

```
public class ApiError {
@SerializedName("error")
private String mErrorDescription;

@SerializedName("code")
private Integer mErrorCode;

public ApiError() {}

public void setErrorCode(Integer code) {
    this.mErrorCode = code;
}

public Integer getErrorCode() {
    return mErrorCode;
}

public String getErrorDescription() {
    return mErrorDescription;
}

public void setErrorDescription(String errorDescription) {
    mErrorDescription = errorDescription;
}
```

}